# python email parsing when transport headers are present

Tags: python, python-3.x

The python emails package is a great tool whilst parsing RFC822 type messages. However, it fails when transport headers are present such as SMTP, POP3, or IMAP. For exapmle:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import email
with open("email.txt") as f:
  msg = email.message_from_file(f)
  print(msg["To"])
```

The above code will not work as expected if SMTP headers are present in email.txt. It will not find the RFC822 in the SMTP.

The various python libraries to handle these protocols (smtplib, poplib, and imaplib) appear to only be useful in communicating with a server and provide no simple parsing capability.

Am I missing something or is there someway to account for the SMTP/POP3/IMAP headers prior to passing RFC822 to the email parsing package?

Comment: Are you referring to the protocol commands like HELO, etc? The tracking envelope data like `Delivered-to` and `Received:` should be okay. Can you post a sample file that isn't working?

Comment: Yes, commands like HELO

Comment: EHLO  
MAIL FROM: <user@user.com>  
RCPT TO: <user2@user.com>  
DATA  
From: "Me" <user@user.com>  
To: <user2@user.com>  
Subject: An Email  
Date: Mon, 5 Oct 2009 11:36:07 +0530  
Message-ID: <000301ca4581$ef9e57f0$ce>  
Content-Type: text/plain;  

Hello this is my email message

Comment: Considering the above text which contains basic SMTP headers followed by an email (after the DATA header).   The email parsing code will not find the email. Is there someway to "parse out" the SMTP headers (or any other protocol headers that may present such as POP)

Comment: Edit your code and add that extra data as a new code block. Makes it easier to see the complete problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to hold the client side of the SMTP conversation used to transmit the email. SMTP separates its headers from the email content with a single line

```
DATA <CRLF>
```

You could discard data until you see that line and have the email left over.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import email
with open("email.txt") as f:
    # discard SMTP conversation
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "DATA":
            break
    else:
        print("no email here")
        exit(0)
    msg = email.message_from_file(f)
    print(msg["To"])
```

If you have multiple SMTP email conversations in the same file, it gets more complicated. You should be able to look for a single line with a "." to find the next message.

Comment: Sure. I could parse the headers or commands myself. I was hoping there was a python library to do it for me.